# Prove the order of each nonindentity element of $G$ is $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Sorry to disturbed, I have an abstract algebra coming and I'm unsure of how to prove this.

If $p$ is prime and $G$ is noncyclic group of order $p^2$, prove the order of each nonindentity element of $G$ is $p$.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Try thinking about it like this.

Every element of the group $G$ has order dividing $|G| = p^2$.

There are three positive integers dividing $p^2$. What are they?

How many elements have order $1$? Can any elements have order $p^2$?

What can you conclude about the orders of the remaining elements of $G$?